# What is the shortest legal zlib compressed stream

Tags: zlib

Here's a short stream

```
>>> import zlib
>>> from binascii import unhexlify
>>> idat = unhexlify(b'789c626001000000ffff030000060005')
>>> zlib.decompress(idat)
b'\x00\x04'
```

But what is the shortest stream using the DEFLATE algorithm that is legal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`78 5e 03 00 00 00 00 01` decompresses to zero bytes.

Comment: Thank you, this is authoritative.

Comment: Of course we are studying `b'\x00\x00'` through `b'\x00\xff'`. If any of them can be deflated into 8 or 9 bytes then there are records to be had!